# Continuous CONNECT/GET requests to web server on port 9485

Tags: flask, tornado, wsgi, cherrypy

I've tried using both CherryPy 3.5 and Tornado 4 to host my Flask WSGI application. Regardless of the WSGI server, every 2s my browser tries to make a CONNECT/GET request to `myserver:9485`.

Chrome's network view looks like this:

[image: chrome]

Firefox's network view looks like this:

[image: ff]
[image: ffdeets]

Finally, IE's network view doesn't show anything, but I do see this in the console:

[image: IE]

Everything about the site works fine, but it kills me knowing this is happening in the background. How do I stop the madness?

Oddly enough, I don't see these messages when I run the code shown below on my development machine.

**Additional details:**

Python 2.7.6, Flask 0.10.1, Angular 1.2.19

CherryPy code:

```
static_handler = tools.staticdir.handler(section='/', dir=app.static_folder)
d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/': app, '/static': static_handler})

server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 9000), d)
server.start()
```

*Probably unrelated, but I am using an EventSource polyfill on one of my pages (I see these messages regardless if I hit that page or not).*

Comment: What *javascript* are you loading from your webpage? Those are websocket connections, and those are entirely *client side initiated*.  They certainly have nothing to do with what WSGI server you are using.

Comment: I'm loading AngularJS with the following modules: ngRoute, angularCharts, ui.bootstrap.buttons, mgcrea.ngStrap, ui.select2, ui.sortable, ngSanitize, ngAnimate, and ngLodash. I communicate with my server via $resource or $http. But, I see these websocket errors on pages where I don't even have a controller.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AngularJS; a quick google doesn't show anything obvious. But you can discount the Flask / Tornado / CherryPy / WSGI angle here, this is entirely client side. Load a *blank page* from your Flask server and the web sockets should go away. If not, try disabling all your extensions and user scripts.

Comment: You're right. Time to isolate sections of my JS

Comment: Doh! It was my [auto-reload-brunch](https://github.com/brunch/auto-reload-brunch) plugin! I simply changed my brunch config to `plugins: autoReload: enabled: false` and the offending JS was removed. Thanks for helping me debug this issue, Martijn